# cant get my mysql insert value if empty code to work even though I have deleted all values in DB it still wont insert

Tags: php, mysql

```
//checks if theyre already are any existing values
$sqlcheck = "SELECT * FROM Merits WHERE u_id ='1'";

$insertmeritsresult = mysqli_query( $link, $sqlcheck);

if($insertmeritsresult == FALSE){
    $u_id = 1;
    $name = "Html5";
    $skill = 4;

    $sql5 = "INSERT INTO Merits( u_id, name, skill)
                VALUES( '$u_id','$name', '$skill')";

    if(mysqli_query($link,$sql5)){

       echo " Values inserted succeful ";
    }
    else{
       echo" error db didnt insert table Merits " ;
    }
}
//this keeps happening allthough it shouldent
else { 
    echo " Merits already       exists " ; 
}
```

Comment: mysqli_query returning FALSE means an _error_ occured, but you want to test whether there is a matching record or not - no matching record is _not_ an error. If you create a unique index for u_id there wil be a specific error code you can test for if a doublet is to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

If your query is valid, and it is, then `$insertmeritsresult` will not be false, as there is no error. It is of course possible for it to return **no rows** in the result set. So instead, count the returned row.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Merits WHERE u_id ='1'";

$result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql);

if($result !== FALSE && mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    $u_id = 1;
    $name = "Html5";
    $skill = 4;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Merits( u_id, name, skill)
                VALUES( '$u_id','$name', '$skill')";

    if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){

       echo " Values inserted succeful ";
    } else{

       // if there is an error its better to show the actual error at least during testing
       echo "error db didnt insert table Merits " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
} else { 
    echo " Merits already       exists " ; 
}
```

Comment: Alright it works now thank you buddy!

Comment: Don't forget to mark as an Accepted Answer with the green check mark below the up and down arrows. If it solved your problem. That's how we roll on the stack.